# Implementing struct that has lifetimes

Tags: rust

Here's my code:

```rust
struct Server<'a> {
    port: &'a u16,
}

impl Server {
    fn connect() {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is with the `impl` block:

```
error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
```

I had to add a lifetime parameter to `Server` to allow the `u16` slice but I do not know how to add one for an `impl` block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have the lifetime annotation on the implementation as well.

```
impl<'a> Server<'a> {
    fn connect() {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: mark it as the answer, if it answered your question :)

Comment: Any reason why you need to specify the lifetime on the keyword as well as on the typename?

Comment: @Milan The first occurrence defines the lifetime. The second one is just one of many places where it can be used. The first occurrence is useful to have because there are more complex lifetime-defining constructs that can be used, such as lifetime bounds, e.g. `impl<'a, 'b, 'a: 'b> Server<'a, 'b> { ... }`. It's also where type parameters are defined, and they themselves can have trait bounds. In simple cases like this though it does feel repetitive, but at least it's consistent.